# How to send uri request via a GET from C# to PHP and get chars encoded as a browser does?

Tags: .net, web

I am making a GET from C#.

```
var result = webClient.DownloadString(
 Microsoft.JScript.GlobalObject.encodeURI(
   "http://www.example.com?value=contacts[contact][0][name]=test man"
);
```

This results in the recieving PHP site:
"value=contacts%5Bcontact%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=test%20man"

After decoding in PHP

```
urldecode($value)
```

"value=contacts%5Bcontact%5D%5B0%5D%5Bname%5D=test man"

So error on the [

But when i paste the url in a browser (IE8 or Chrome) i get this results in the recieving PHP site:
"value=contacts[contact][0][name]=test%20man"

IE. The browser sends the request (url) in a workable encoding, my code does not.

How do I use the GET with the correct encoding, as the browsers do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a lot of chars that had higher Code Points, that needs a %25 infront to parse right in PHP.
Ex. å = %C3%E5 in encoding .NET
but shold be:
%25C3%25E5

So I made a function for correcting this, it is not complete for reuse, but will be if all other codes are added.

```
        var urlCodes = new [] { "20", "C3", "84", "85", "96", "A4", "A5", "B6", "2C", "C2", "A0", "2F", "40", "3A" };

        foreach (var stringsUrlCodes in urlCodes)
        {
            encodedUrl = encodedUrl.Replace("%" + stringsUrlCodes.ToString(), "%25" + stringsUrlCodes.ToString().Replace("%", string.Empty));
        }
```